# Two hangup events in one call hangup in asterisk call

Tags: asterisk

I am using asterisk call file to make call and I want to send message to caller after call ends that he has called for this much duration. I wrote code for sending message in hangup event. Now the problem I am facing is when call is ended hangup event is fired two times for calling party and called party as well, which results in sending two messages to caller. Can any one suggests any idea how can I handle this thing that once code is executed it will not execute again for same call.

**Edit 1:** Following is the code that I want to avoid to be execuated twice for same call.

```
LogProperties.log.debug("[" + refID + "] Channel HUNGUP on id: " + channelID);
LogProperties.log.debug("Channel hungup on id: " + channelID);
Object channelObj = EventMonitor.requestsMap.get(channelID);
if (channelObj != null) {
    ChargingTask activeTask = (ChargingTask) channelObj;
    LogProperties.log.info("[" + refID + "] Cancelling changing task on channelID: " + channelID);
    activeTask.cancel();
} 
else {
    String otherChannelID = (String) EventMonitor.linkedChannels.get(channelID);
    LogProperties.log.info("[" + refID + "] Cannot Cancel changing task against channelID: " + channelID + ", Now looking for other linked channel, ID: " + otherChannelID);
    channelObj = EventMonitor.requestsMap.get(otherChannelID);
    if (channelObj != null) {
        ChargingTask activeTask = (ChargingTask) channelObj;
        LogProperties.log.info("[" + refID + "] Cancelling changing task for channelID: " + otherChannelID);
        activeTask.cancel();
    }
    else{
        LogProperties.log.error("[" + refID + "] Still cannot Cancel Charging Task");
    }
}
Utilities.removeMemcachedEntry(channelID);
Utilities.ClearHashtables(channelID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seams you have do that based on cdr (mysql table check).

Other solution - determine which channel is origunate,remember it an send even only iif hangup have channel from list.

No,you can't force asterisk do that instead of you.

Comment: Other solution worked for me i captured channel on first hangup event only which solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to ask what event of asterisk have you used to handle the call end event ?